# Argument valid?

Tags: logic

Some mathematicians are brilliant. Some brilliant people are crazy. Therefore some mathematicians are crazy.

Is it correct to say that the argument above is invalid because the negation is true? Or is my negation wrongly written?

Negation: All mathematicians are brilliant. All brilliant people are crazy. Therefore all mathematicians are crazy, which is obviously true.

Comment: Your negation is very wrong.

Comment: In order to prove that the statement $p \implies q$ is false, you can simply show a counterexample in which $p$ is true and $q$ is false. If you want to prove that the negation is true, then you need to prove $\neg(p \implies q)$.

Comment: This is some high quality trolling, I'll give you that. The punchline comes so late in the question that most users will already write their answers before they notice it. I admit I did. But still, please, remove the question now. We had our fun.

Comment: Im sorry, im not trolling and this is a question in one of my university logic tutorial, im very new to logic and i just want to know if my negation is correctly constructed. If it is not, then may i know what's wrong with it? Or how can i say that the argument is invalid without using the negation?

Comment: Yeah, why are we automatically assuming that OP is trolling?

Comment: Some women are blond. Some blonde people are men. Therefore, some women are men.

Comment: thank you very much @Mauro, that counterexample helped a lot haha. But is my negation written wrongly?

Comment: Yes, the negation of "some $x$ are $S$" is **not** "all $x$ are $S$."

Comment: Are you actually trying to negate the original statement or are you trying to establish its validity?

Comment: Negate the original statement and establish the validity of the negation so as to conclude if the original statement is valid or not.

Comment: @tilper The sentence "Therefore all mathematicians are crazy, which is obviously true." gives it away...

Comment: I wrote "obviously true" because it was a lot easier to determine the validity of the negation i wrote (though wrongly written), i mean nothing else.

Comment: @5xum, I'm a little perturbed that you ended that with "gives it away..." as if you still believe it's trolling. While this can be **interpreted** as such, one must also realize there is a **possibility** this question can be given by some math teacher somewhere to his or her students. Also, OP already clarified, (needlessly) apologized, & accepted an answer. And we can see an earlier, more innocuous question in OP's profile. While trolling is a possibility, there is more evidence to the contrary. Please let us avoid jumping to conclusions on  this site so as not to create a toxic environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally your statement has a form:

$$A:=\exists x (M(x)\ \wedge\ B(x)), B:=\exists x (B(x)\ \wedge\ C(x))\text{ implies } C:=\exists x (M(x)\ \wedge C(x)) $$
First of all $\neg A$, negation of $A$, is $\forall x (M(x)\to \neg B(x))$, i.e. $\neg A$ read as 'no mathematician is briliant'.

And the negation of the whole statement of yours would be

$$A\ \wedge\ B \ \wedge \neg C$$